# Global variables in Google Apps Script: access them from on script to other script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to access global variables of the same google apps script project in one script file in other script of the same project? I could access some variables (ex: folderID), but not other variable (like: emails in a function to send emails).

Comment: If you're more comfortable with it then do it, there are no restrictions at all... :-)  I do it sometimes for long scripts.

Comment: But there are restrictions? I try put all my global variables in a script, but some variables aren't accessed.

Comment: Your issues must be somewhere else... there are no restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no restrictions, its standard javascript.
You must be having some other problem like duplicate variable names or wrong scope (not global)